# Image on top of image on mouseover

Tags: javascript, window, modal-dialog

I'm looking at how to do something similar to this page: http://www.gap.com/browse/category.do?cid=15043

When you mouseover a shirt, it shows the Quick Look image. I can not figure out how to show the image when you mouseover. The tricky part is that you can still click on the shirt and then that will take you to the product page. If you click on the Quick Look image it takes you to a modal window. I've got the modal window working the way I want, I just don't know how to display a Quick Look type image over the main product image on mouse over.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think to do this is to use jquery to make an onmouseover event that swaps the image reference for the new reference, then make an onmouseout event that puts the original image reference back in place

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to accomplish this. I use a `div` in this example but and image should work as well: [**Live example**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/qnN96/)

**html**

```
<a href="#"><div class="img">info here</div></a>
```

**css**

```
a{
    display:block;
    background-color:#666;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

a div.img{
    display:none;
}

a:hover div.img{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: That worked really well for me. Thanks! How do I make it so that if you click on the Grey box you go to 1 destination, but if you click on 'info here' you are taken to a different destination?

Comment: @Ryan adding a click handler to the popup image should work. example http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/qnN96/10/